# Django: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

    contact = models.BigIntegerField()

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, null=False)

    password = models.TextField(max_length=30)
```

**form.py**

```
class CreateEmployee(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Your Name", max_length=30, required=True)

    contact = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    Email = forms.EmailField(max_length=40, widget=forms.EmailInput(), required=True)

    password = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

**views.py**

```
class Create_Employee(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'employee.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = CreateEmployee()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):

        try:

            data = request.POST.get

            Employee(name=data('name'),

                     contact=data('contact'),

                     email=data('email'),

                     password=data('password')

                     ).save()

            return HttpResponse("Employee has been added successfully", 200)

        except Exception as e:

            return HttpResponse("Failed: {}".format(e), 500)
```

After submitting the form, I get this error:

> Failed: null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (20, usman, 31902355, null, 123456s).

Comment: Email at `Email = forms.EmailField(...` First letter is a capital letter, is this a typo?

Comment: May I kindly suggest you learn to properly use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) and [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms) ? This would save you a lot of time, pain and security issues.

Comment: no e is small in email

Comment: i use django.views.generic

Comment: how can solve the issue of null value

Comment: It seems that there is no data of email in `POST` request

Comment: try ` email=data('email') or 'abc@xyz.com',` and it will save `abc@xyz.com`.

Comment: i write email = data('email') in view.py but still it show error

Comment: try `email=data('email') or 'abc@xyz.com'`